# testing variables from a text list to set value in batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

what I have is a text document full of variables to set and test called test.txt

```
ab <-example variable
```

and a batch program that pulls from the list

```
for /f %%a in ('type test.txt') do set %%a=0
for /f %%a in ('type test.txt') do echo %%%a%
```

expected output

```
0
```

actual output

```
%ab%
```

this is a really stripped down example but that is the problem
I have tried typing

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

in the command line but that alone dose nothing and

```
for /f %%a in ('type test.txt') do echo !%%a!
```

just outputs

```
!ab!
```

Comment: Your modification solve the problem! I suggest you to rollback this modification; otherwise, your question is nonsense now, because it don't fail anymore...

Comment: but it didn't solve the problem testing it in batch and not cmd solved the problem it was an environment issue

Comment: Err... The only problem in this question _as you posted it_ is the typo in the `setlocal enabledelayedexpanTion`, as [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262112/testing-variables-from-a-text-list-to-set-value-in-batch/27262738#27262738) proved. Although `setlocal` command does not works in the command-line (as `setlocal /?` indicate) you mentioned nothing about this point in your question. You may post a new question about this point if you wish...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpantion
                           ^ Here!
```

It should be:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

**EDIT**: *Example session added*

```
C:\ type test.txt
ab


C:\ type test.bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%a in ('type test.txt') do set %%a=0
for /f %%a in ('type test.txt') do echo !%%a!


C:\ test
0
```

Comment: I see what I missed, turns out delayed expansion only works in a batch file. I was testing by just typing it into cmd and getting false negatives

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
for /f %%a in ('type q27262112.txt') do set %%a=0
for /f %%a in ('type q27262112.txt') do echo %%%a%
for /f %%a in ('type q27262112.txt') do CALL echo %%%%a%%
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f %%a in ('type q27262112.txt') do set %%a=w
for /f %%a in ('type q27262112.txt') do echo !%%a!
GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q27262112.txt` containing your data for my testing.

This produced the following output:

```
%
0
w
```

This differs from your results but demonstrates how to retrieve the value of variable `ab`.

I set the value of `ab` deliberately in the `delayedexpansion` instance to some-value-other-than-0 to demonstrate that the value retrieved was indeed being set, not a hangover.